# APS formt - how to include email id of all authors

Tags: author

How to include email id of all Authors but the first Author is the primary contact. Both the Authors belong to the same department and same university. Also, I want ot know for another paper, how to make the second Author as the primary contact. So, the primary contact appears as `*`. 
With the following code, I am not getting the email id. What is the correct format? Thank you

```
  \documentclass[aps,prl,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{bm}        % for math
\usepackage{verbatim}   % for math
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\revtex}{REV\TeX\ }
\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{Im}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\newenvironment{psmallmatrix}
  {\left[\begin{smallmatrix}}
  {\end{smallmatrix}\right]}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage {extarrows}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\title{Tips for delicious cooking for graduate student life}%

\author{Stressed student 1}%,
 \author{Stressed student 1}
\email[student1@gmail.com]{student1@gmail.com}
\affiliation{Department}
\date{June xx, 2017}%
\begin{abstract}
This document shares some tips for cost effective living and budget friendly delicious healthy food.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\section{I. Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place a `\email` after each author with the appropriate address (the same way one would handle distinct affiliations).

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}

\author{Foo}
\email{foo@baz.com}

\author{Bar}
\email{bar@baz.com}
\affiliation{Department}

\date{June 29, 2017}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the solution that I am looking, however, how to include all the emails but differentiate between the primary contact. For example, Mr Bar is the primary contact (eventhough he is the second author)but the email id of Mr Foo should also appear in the document.

Comment: I believe the norm in APS journals is to only give email addresses for any corresponding authors (https://journals.aps.org/prl/info/infoL.html#title) in one row at the end, you could use `\email[Corresponding author: ]{bar@baz.com}` to make it clear in the endnote that Bar is the preferred contact to Foo.  If you want to give Foo's email in an endnote though, I think you really need to associate it with Foo by putting Foo* in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Tips for delicious cooking for graduate student life}
\author[*]{Stressed student 1}
\author[ ]{Stressed student 2}

%   \author[1]{Author C}
%   \author[2]{Author D}
%   \author[2]{Author E}

\affil[*]{Department of Stress, Strs University}

\affil[*]{\textit student1@gmail.com}
\affil[ ]{\textit student2@gmail.com}
\date{June xx, 2017}


\maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    This document shares some tips for cost effective living and budget friendly delicious healthy food.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This makes it appear that the second author is not affiliated to a university.  It also seems to be incompatible with [`revtex4-1`](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) which may or may not be prohibitive depending on the OP's needs.